# How can I find TouchableOpacity component's delayLongPress property default value in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I couldn't find any docs or knowledge about this value. Are these values determined at the java level for android?

Comment: You should look into Pressable instead of TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ***500 milliseconds***.

You can find out in the code file in `node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\TouchableOpacity.js`.

**TouchableOpacity.js**

```
import Pressability, {
  type PressabilityConfig,
} from '../../Pressability/Pressability';

_createPressabilityConfig(): PressabilityConfig {
    return {
      ...
      delayLongPress: this.props.delayLongPress,
      ...
    };
  }
```

As you may see, it is defined in Pressability.js.

**Pressability.js**

```
  /**
   * Duration (in addition to `delayPressIn`) after which a press gesture is
   * considered a long press gesture. Defaults to 500 (milliseconds).
   */
  delayLongPress?: ?number,
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the basic default values for all the  touchableOpacity attributes below,

```html
enabled: If true, parallax effects are enabled. Defaults to true.
shiftDistanceX: Defaults to 2.0.
shiftDistanceY: Defaults to 2.0.
tiltAngle: Defaults to 0.05.
magnification: Defaults to 1.0.
pressMagnification: Defaults to 1.0.
pressDuration: Defaults to 0.3.
pressDelay: Defaults to 0.0.
```

[And you may find all these in here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)